# The drop down element is not locating

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, cypress

Requirement : *Click on the drop down and the drop down should open*.

DOM:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="3522" style="width: 208.328px;" xpath="1">
<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-_ID-container" aria-owns="select2_ID-results" aria-activedescendant="select2_ID-result-pwlg-2">
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2_ID-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Choose Inco Term">Choose Inco Term</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"></b>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

The element is located on the UI:
But when I use the same id on the code as below:

```
cy.get('#select2_ID-container').click({force:true})
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: #select2_ID-container, but never found it.
```

I also tried `{force: true}`:

```
cy.get('#select2_ID-container').click({force:true})
```

Comment: I couldn't find `select2-Shipment_ID-container` in the above code snippet. Is the ID provided correct? - Or can you edit the post to add that part as well.

Comment: Removed nodejs tag.

Comment: Sorry. Yes the id is correct. I posted incorrect code. Have corrected.

Comment: No problem. Please select the best answer (green tick mark should come when you select) if it worked for you. Let's help others to get the best / correct answer too.

Comment: No still not working.

Comment: Can you change span to div for select2_ID-container ? - just to try if it works. Also confirm, whether it is being hidden in some way (the element should be present on the DOM)

Answer (score 4):

There is a different id shown above, perhaps you want

```js
cy.get('[id="select2_ID-container"]').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for `role="combobox"`, since this is likely to be the dropdown.

```js
cy.get('span[role="combobox"]').click({force:true})
```

Comment: Can't use this sice there are other elements associated with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

`#select2_ID-container` is the selector for the first option in the dropdown list which is `Choose Inco Term`. You can use this to open the drop down.

```js
cy.get('[aria-owns="select2_ID-results"]').click()
OR
cy.get('[aria-activedescendant="select2_ID-result-pwlg-2"]').click()
```

Or, You can also use the text to find and click.

```js
cy.contains('Choose Customer').click()
```

Comment: How about using these `[aria-owns="select2_ID-results"]` or `[aria-activedescendant="select2_ID-result-pwlg-2"]` ? Or directly using `cy.contains('Choose Customer').click()`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery select2 has a visible textbox which can be clicked to show the options.

If you're having trouble with the ID, this is how I would approach the test

```js
cy.get('.select2 [title="Choose Inco Term"]')
  .as('select2')                              // alias the textbox
  .click()                                    // open the options list

// Options now open
cy.contains('li.select2-results__option', 'TextOfOption').click()  // choose an option

// Verify
cy.get('@select2')
  .find('li.select2-selection__choice')     // choice is listed under textbox
  .should('contain', 'TextOfOption')        // check the text

// Remove
cy.get('@select2')
  .find('.select2-selection__choice__remove')  // remove button
  .click()

cy.get('@select2')
  .should('not.contain', 'TextOfOption')       // check text has gone
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes cypress requires a mouse move. Try this too:

```
cy.get('[id="select2_ID-container"]').trigger('mousemove').click()
```

Also make sure the element is present / not timedout by checking the command logs : https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Command-Log

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to this. I tried all of the above solutions, but neither worked for me. This was due to the version issue. I simple updated the Cypress to the latest version 10.0.1 and ran the test and it worked. Also the dropdown is not located because the page was not loaded properly. The click action was performed on the automation before the page loads completely. So I added cy.wait(10000) before clicking the dropdown. I think the version is not the main problem. The main problem is the page load.
Thank you all for your time. :)